# How do I make high quality food?

Tags: fantasy-life

A bunch of my Chef challenges require me to make high quality food. Obviously, my dishes are not cutting it. What do I have to do to make high quality food?

Comment: For other crafts, raising my Crafting level and using higher quality tools helped me get high quality items easier (bars fill faster).  I would assume it's the same for Cooking.

Answer (score 3):

Improve your Focus and Dexterity and some high quality tools is the way to go.

There is no secret to this, always use the life level tool (lvl 2 cook with silver frying pan, etc) and put some points in the main status of the life.